# Leaflet in Angular not resizing correctly

Tags: angular, leaflet, ngx-leaflet

I'm using Leaflet in an Angular 10 project, via @ngx-leaflet component and ran into a scenario that has been driving me nuts for the last couple of weeks, see the screen shot below:

When users use the zoom-in, zoom-out, enter full screen, exit full screen toggles or even changing the zoom level in the browser, it renders 2 or 3 tiles and places grey images throughout the map.

The map div is wrapped in another DIV that's a flexbox, so I initially thought it's flex that's not giving the map div enough time to render (as the map should always be 100% h, 100% w), so removed the flex on the container, no different.

I then thought it might be related to the bounds that I'm fitting the map position to (as I'm rendering polygons) so removed the .fitToBounds(...) call to see if it makes any different, which it didn't.

I then went in an added a @HostListener for resize, and tried invalidating the size on the map instance, but this has absolutely no effect.

I've read numerous blogs and SO articles relating to this, unfortunately, I'm not any closers trying to resolve this.

For reference, here's the map control's HTML:

```html
<div class="map-container" fxFlex>
    <div fxFlex="1 0 auto" class="map-leaflet w-100-p h-100-p">
        <div leaflet
            class="w-100-p h-100-p"
            #leafletMmap
            [attr.id]="'leaflet-map'"
            [leafletOptions]="options"
            (leafletMapReady)="onMapReady($event)"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the TS file, for [leafletOptions]:

```js
  options = {
    layers: [
      tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s,h&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
        maxZoom: 20,
        subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3']
      })
    ],
    zoom: 7,
    center: latLng(-25.1056, 26.9847),
  };
```

and the @HostListener

```js
  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event) {
    if (this.mapInstance) {
      this.mapInstance.on('viewreset', (value) => {
        this.mapInstance.invalidateSize();
      });

      this.mapInstance.on('resize', (value) => {
        this.mapInstance.invalidateSize();
      });
    }
  }
```

and then, I have a component that receives a map instance from the map component, and every interaction on the map happens from within this; just an extra from adding the polygons:

```js
if (fence.geometryAsGeoJson) {
  const json = Utilities.geoJsonObject([fence]);

  const geolayer = geoJSON(json as any, {
    style
  });

  boundingbox.push(geolayer.getBounds());

  this.mapInstance.addLayer(geolayer);

  const fenceLabelIcon = divIcon({
    iconSize: null,
    html: `<center><div class="floattext ${fence.id}">${fence.caption}</div></center>`,
    className: `marker-pill fence-divicon`
  });

  const fenceLabel = marker(geolayer.getBounds().getCenter(), {
    icon: fenceLabelIcon,
    className: `fence-${fence.id}`
  } as any);

  this.fencelabels.push(fenceLabel);
}
```

I don't believe I'm doing any ridiculous that would cause Leaflet to misbehave. Any idea what I might be missing?

[image]

Comment: You have not specified if resizing the browser window makes the map suddenly work?

Comment: @ghybs on the contrary, resizing the browser window is even worse. in the screen shot, using the +/- buttons (custom), it would fill 3 or 4 tiles, as soon as you resize the browser window all tiles disappear completely, or a single tile is rendered outside of view, somewhere near the top left or top right.

Comment: Wow first time I am reading such an odd behaviour indeed! Seems like something broken with your setup. Your question would definitely benefit from having a live reproduction example (StackBlitz, codesandbox, etc.). Maybe a race condition with Angular, flex and Leaflet trying to read the flex size.

Comment: @ghybs that's exactly what i thought as well. trying to reproduce, will update. was very weird when i started looking for a solution to this, that many people say resizing the window fixes their problem where the opposite is true for my scenario. will update when i have something concrete.